# How to create keyboard shortcuts with Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm having trouble trying to find a way to create keyboard shortcuts with it. I mean, where and how can I code something like ctrl + t increases font size of the site?

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: In your main app, child component, or a service that you want to handle events, use `fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(window, 'keyup').subscribe(evt => /* Handle the keyboard events */)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course this can be accomplished with vanilla javascript, but Angular has the `@HostListener` decorator to make listening for events simpler: https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener

You put the decorator over a component's function to add an event listener that executes the function on an event.

Don't use ctrl + t though, that's "new tab" for all browsers, and I don't believe you can override it.

To listen for ctrl + b on the entire window it would be like this:

```js
  @HostListener('window:keydown.control.b', ['$event'])
  bigFont(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.body.style.fontSize = '32px';
  }
```

`event.preventDefault()` prevents any default browser actions caused by the event, if possible.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2rhyep?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Note: the listeners are cleaned up if the enclosing component is destroyed.